# Tracking the mouse in a DIV Element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to track the users mouse and display the X & Y coordinates but only if the mouse is in the specific div element called "spielfeld". When the mouse leaves the div element the code should not track the mouse anymore.

So here is my code:

```
<div id="spielfeld">

  <a id="x_result>0</a>
  <a id="y_result>0</a>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function MouseTrack(e) {
          var result_x = document.getElementById('x_result')
          var result_y = document.getElementById('y_result')

          result_x.innerHTML = e.layerX;
          result_y.innerHTML = e.layerY;
        }

        document.onmousemove = MouseTrack;

      </script>
</div>
```

This code displays the correct position for each element the mouse is over. 
But not for an specific element.

Comment: Your goal is to get relative cursor position to the div or update the cursor's position only when it is inside the element?

Comment: Yes, it should only update if the cursor is in the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to place the event on the div you want to track the mouse on

```
<div id="spielfeld">

  <a id="x_result>0</a>
  <a id="y_result>0</a>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function MouseTrack(e) {
           // don't use layerX and layerY they are non standard . 
           // select dom element and update here . 
           console.log(e.screenX , e.screenY)
        }

        document.querySelector('#spielfeld').addEventListener('mousemove' , MouseTrack)  

      </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `document.onmousemove = MouseTrack;` to:
`document.getElementById('spielfeld').onmousemove = MouseTrack;`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the working code below;

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="Show">
<input type="text" name="MouseX" value="0" size="7"> X<br>
<input type="text" name="MouseY" value="0" size="7"> Y<br>
</form>
<script>

var s= document.all?true:false

if (!s) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

var tempX = 0
var tempY = 0

function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (s) { 
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
  } else {  
    tempX = e.pageX
    tempY = e.pageY
  }  

  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX
  document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY
  return true
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```